# ajax add_endRequest never fires, on iPad only

Tags: ajax, telerik

I have some asp code in which I have a set of Telerik grids on separate jQueryUI tabs, and I am lazy-loading the grid data so that the grids only bind to live data if you actually view the tab that contains them. The rebind causes an ajax postback, and I have added an endRequest handler to re-apply the jQueryUI formatting once the request returns. This is working in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE. But on the iPad the endRequest handler never fires. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

My code is as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    (function ($, Sys) {
        function setUpEmsDashboard() {
            $('#emsDashboard').dnnTabs().dnnPanels();

            $('#dInvoiceLink').click(function () {
                lazyLoadOutstandingInvoicesGrid();
            });

            if ($('#dInvoice').is(':visible')) {
                lazyLoadOutstandingInvoicesGrid();
            }

            $('#dCountsForStaffLink').click(function () {
                lazyLoadCountsForStaffGrids();
            });

            if ($('#dCountsForStaff').is(':visible')) {
                lazyLoadCountsForStaffGrids();
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setUpEmsDashboard();
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
                setUpEmsDashboard();
            });
        });
    } (jQuery, window.Sys));
</script>
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function lazyLoadOutstandingInvoicesGrid() {
            var grid = $find("<%=OutstandingInvoicesGrid.ClientID%>");
            var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
            var name = masterTableView.get_name();
            if (name == 'Temp Data') {
                masterTableView.rebind();
            }
            return true;
        }

        function lazyLoadCountsForStaffGrids() {
            var countsBySalesRegionGrid = $find("<%=CountsBySalesRegionGrid.ClientID%>");
            var cbsrMasterTableView = countsBySalesRegionGrid.get_masterTableView();
            var cbsrName = cbsrMasterTableView.get_name();
            if (cbsrName == 'Temp Data') {
                cbsrMasterTableView.rebind();
                return true;
            }
            var countsBySupplierTypeGrid = $find("<%=CountsBySupplierTypeGrid.ClientID%>");
            var cbstMasterTableView = countsBySupplierTypeGrid.get_masterTableView();
            var cbstName = cbstMasterTableView.get_name();
            if (cbstName == 'Temp Data') {
                cbstMasterTableView.rebind();
                return true;
            }
            var countsByCategoryGrid = $find("<%=CountsByCategoryGrid.ClientID%>");
            var cbcMasterTableView = countsByCategoryGrid.get_masterTableView();
            var cbcName = cbcMasterTableView.get_name();
            if (cbcName == 'Temp Data') {
                cbcMasterTableView.rebind();
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the issue. What I had was a race condition where for some browsers in some circumstances, the grid objects were null.

I changed:

```
    function lazyLoadOutstandingInvoicesGrid() {
        var grid = $find("<%=OutstandingInvoicesGrid.ClientID%>");
        var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
        var name = masterTableView.get_name();
        if (name == 'Temp Data') {
            masterTableView.rebind();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

to:

```
    function lazyLoadOutstandingInvoicesGrid() {
        var grid = $find("<%=OutstandingInvoicesGrid.ClientID%>");
        if (typeof (grid) !== 'undefined' && grid != null) {
            var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
            var name = masterTableView.get_name();
            if (name == 'Temp Data') {
                masterTableView.rebind();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

...and made similar changes to the other function. That prevented the object reference error that had been silently causing the rest of the main function to fail. Now it works consistently.